Creating pyd for python project
I have simple python project which represents basic inheritance tree.
mypackage:

__init__.py
animal.py   (class Animal)
dog.py      (class Dog inherited from Animal)

I want to generate 'single' distributable pyd so that I can use anywhere.
I am new to such type of scenario. Help is appriciated
I tried with cython. I could generate single pyd but could not import modules from it.
import mypackage.animal throws error as module not found

I think it should be __init__.py instead of init.py

"I want to generate 'single' distributable pyd": why? Doesn't make much sense. Do you know what a .pyd is / does?
